# Solve the initial-value problem on the specified interval. $xy'-2y=4x^3y^{1/2}$ with $y=0$ when $x=1$ on $(- \infty,+ \infty)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

> Solve the initial-value problem on the specified interval.
>   $$xy'-2y=4x^3y^{1/2} \text{  with  } y=0 \text{  when  } x=1 \text{  on  } (- \infty,+ \infty)$$ .

There're two points $(x=1,x=0)$ on $(- \infty,+ \infty)$ such that $y=0$. So I suppose $y \neq 0$ on these intervals $(- \infty,0),(0,1),(1, + \infty)  $ and it's equals to solve a nonzero solution for $g(x) =y^{1/2} $ which satisfies $g'(x)- \frac{1}{x}g(x)=2x^2$ on these intervals with $g(-1)=b_1 ,g(\frac{1}{2})=b_2 ,g(2)=b_3 ,(b_k \neq 0)$

So I have $$g(x)=x^3+C_1x,(C_1=1-b_1, x \in ( - \infty,0))$$
          $$g(x)=x^3+C_2x, (C_2 = 2b_2- \frac{1}{4},x \in (0,1))$$
          $$ g(x)=x^3+C_3x,(C_3 = \frac{b_3}{2}-4, x \in (1, + \infty))$$
But $y=0$ when $x=1$,I don't know whether it's convenient to define $g(1)=0$ and how I should do to extend the solution to $(- \infty, + \infty)$.

> P.S.: I've noticed the constant $y=0$ is also a solution but the exercise wants me to solve it by using the technic I described above. If I let the solutions on $(0,1)$ and $(1,+\infty)$ both tend to $0$ as $x \to 1$ I get $C_2,C_3$ both $-1$,but I need  help to formalize the solution when extending the solution on $(- \infty,+ \infty)$.

Comment: let $x=0$,you'll get $0y'-2y=4 0^3 y^{1/2}$,so $y=0$ when $x=0$

Comment: This is the point.I solve $g(x)$ for those intervals $y \neq 0$.So I have no idea to do with $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\frac{x^2 y' - 2 x y}{x^4} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{y}{x^2} = 4 y^{1/2}= 4 |x| \left ( \frac{y}{x^2}\right )^{1/2}$$

Assume for the moment that $x \gt 0$.  Then

$$ \left ( \frac{y}{x^2}\right )^{1/2} = x^2 +C$$
$$y(1)=0 \implies C=-1$$

so that

$$y(x) = x^2 (x^2-1)^2 \quad x\gt 0$$

Similarly

$$y(x) = x^2 (x^2+1)^2 \quad x\lt 0$$

Thus,

$$y(x) = x^2 (x^2-\operatorname*{sgn}{x})^2$$

Comment: hi,I notice you convert it to $g'(x)=4|x|g^{1/2}$ which $g(x)= \frac{y}{x^2}$,but did you solve $g(x)$ by using $v=g^{1/2}$? I think it's a problem cause $g(1)=0$

Comment: @DetectiveKing: not quite understanding you.  That $g(1)=0$ is no problem here, as we solved for $g$ and not $g'$ there.

Comment: Could you  give more details about how you solve $g'(x)=4|x|g^{1/2}$.I can solve it if I use $v=g^{1/2}$,but it involve some calculation which contains g(x) in the denominator.

Comment: @DetectiveKing: it is straightforward - you end up integrating $g^{-1/2} dg = 4 |x| dx$ to get $g^{1/2}$.

Comment: yes. you use $g^{-1/2}$ didn't it means $g \neq 0$?

Comment: @DetectiveKing: Not if $g'(1)=0$ as well.

Comment: Hi,could you add more details in your answer about the way you checking the point $x=0,x=1$ and the way you check the constant $C$ when $x<0$,I need help to formalize the solution when combining these internals.